# A light ray grazing over a spherical material

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, geometric-optics

If an incident ray just grazes over a sphere of refractive index '$n$' then will it suffer any deviation or not?

According to my reasoning it shouldn't suffer and deviation as the the ray will be perpendicular to the normal of the surface and should pass undeviated. Moreover, it doesn't actually never enters the medium.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is true, if we consider geometrical optics. However, geometrical optics is usually considered to be a special case of the wave description of light, and considering the same situation using a wave description leads to diffraction.

Using Huygen's principle, each disturbed point in space acts as source of a secondary spherical wave. Theses secondary waves interfer and generate the field distribution $E(x,y,z)$. Therefore, there are waves entering the medium. Furthermore, we expect **diffractions** in the regime "behind" the medium. However, the diffraction effects can  be rather small: If you consider a well collimated laser beam, with Gaussian beam waist in the order of  $mm$, the diffraction effects are "small", because the medium effects only the secondary waves in its "vicinity" -- across few wavelengths. Thus, if 99% of the beam is not affected by the existence of the medium, the overall diffraction effect I usually considered to be small.